# Read a text in a table on a google slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have several pages in a google slides, all with the same format and 2 tables, one on each side of the slide with several fields each.

How do I recover in a variable the text field of a special field with a unique ID that changes in each of the pages.

I'd like to use Apps script

Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Inserting, deleting, or replacing text
There are two ways you can replace text in a presentation using the Slides API: by performing a global search-and-replace, or by explicitly deleting and adding text. Both ways use the batchUpdate method, but with different request types. Global search and replace
Use ReplaceAllTextRequest to do a global search-and-replace throughout your presentation.

The Text Merging section of the Merging Data guide provides an example of how you can use this request type.  https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/styling